# What is a public interface?

Tags: java

*"Using only the public interface of the linked list class, write a method
    public static void reverse(LinkedList staff)
that reverses the entries in a linked list."*

The part of all of that I'm not understanding is the first part. What does it mean by public interface of linked list class? Do I create a new class file that starts with something like *public interface linkedlist*? Can I add the method as a inner class within my main class?

Answer (score 7):

The question is unnecessarily vague. What it's trying to ask is "using only the methods and fields of `LinkedList` that have the access modifier `public`, write this method."

You can put the method you write in any class you like, but the restriction says that you may only use `public` methods and fields on `LinkedList` to write it.

This also means that you can't create a subclass of `LinkedList` and use its `protected` methods.

Comment: Yes. That is also my interpretation. I think this phrase is a polite way of saying: "If you use some `reverse` method you are getting a big round 0". The thing is, if this is the standard collections API `LinkedList` class, a smart lazy student could go for [Collections.reverse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) or maybe pull some [Guava Magic](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse(java.util.List)). Things are pretty funny at the academy :D.

Comment: Been there, done that (had my share of zeros)... And today I would definitively hire the smart ass - don't reinvent the wheel adept - student.

Answer (score 2):

The public interface of a class are its public properties (variables or fields you can read the values of or assign to) and methods (functions you can call).

So, the assignment is to create something that is not a subclass of `LinkedList`. Creating a subclass would give you access to protected methods for example. You need to create something external to LinkedList, for example:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();

    // do something with l here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Public interface of linked list class" means only public methods of the LinkedList class. See [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), there is a list of all public methods, or create new LinkedList instance and let your IDE suggest.